# Cant find origin of Unhandled 'error' event ETIMEDOUT

Tags: node.js, rest, express, http

I am building an application that is communicating with a local server through http requests, I decided to do a "real" test and it keeps throwing errors, but I cant track where the error is coming from, the stacktrace doesnt tell me where it originates from (in my app).
When I start my app it works for 20-30 seconds, it manages to get/send data to that local webserver, but after 20-30 seconds I get the following error:

```
events.js:287
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 192.168.55.213:80
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16)
Emitted 'error' event on ClientRequest instance at:
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:426:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '192.168.55.213',
  port: 80
}
```

I have tried all my http requests in a try/catch block and log the errors to try and pinpoint where it originates from but nothing, the try/catches dont work, because the error is still being thrown, so it is not from within my http requests and I cant figure out the origin of the error. My requests look something like this:

```
async RequestFunction(requesturl) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
            http.get(requesturl, (resp) => { 
                let data = "";
                resp.on('data', (chunk) => data += chunk)
                resolve(data)
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(`${requesturl}+${error.code}`);
        }
    }
}
```

But the catch never gets triggered. I am guessing that mostly what I am asking for is how to track where the error is originating from?

I have also tried wrapping my Request function in every place where I am calling and awaiting it with a try/catch block, same thing.

Comment: Have you try to use the flag  `NODE_DEBUG='net,tls,http,https'` to debug?

Comment: @abestrad No I haven't I wasnt even aware of it. How do I use that?

Comment: I tried this but it doesnt output anything set DEBUG='http,https,net,tls' & node app.js

Comment: hmm,  `return new Prommise`  is the actual code? think should be `Promise`

Comment: @abestrad no, sorry it was a typo, because I was manually typing the pseudo code here :), so how do I use this NODE_DEBUG? I tried a few things but couldnt figure out the issue and get it to work